Почему авторизации на телефоне, не переходит на страницу профиля. На пк все работает отлично
производил авторизацию благодаря firebase authentication + firestore database. На пк после входа переходит на страницу профиля, а с телефона нет. Вот мой код
googleSignInButton.addEventListener("click", async () => {
googleSignInButton.disabled = true;

try {
    const isMobile = /iPhone|iPad|iPod|Android/i.test(navigator.userAgent);

    if (isMobile) {
        await signInWithRedirect(auth, provider);
    } else {
        const result = await signInWithPopup(auth, provider);
        const user = result.user;

        console.log("User signed in: ", user);

        const userDocRef = doc(db, "users", user.uid);
        const docSnap = await getDoc(userDocRef);

        if (!docSnap.exists()) {
            await setDoc(userDocRef, {
                uid: user.uid,
                email: user.email,
                displayName: user.displayName,
                balance: 0,
                cardStatus: false
            });
            console.log("User added to Firestore");
        }

        window.location.href = "https://unis2.store/maldenaHealth/profile";
    }
} catch (error) {
    console.error("Error during Google sign-in: ", error.message);
} finally {
    googleSignInButton.disabled = false;
}

});
